# Flip row table one by one with delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a table with 3 colum and 10 row
i want flip the row one by one
the row have data front & back
i need flip the row similar like this

http://jsfiddle.net/asomani/kr4s4k7f/4/

but flip one by one from top row to last row, and flip again from top to last

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.flashcard').toggleClass('flipped');
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.stage {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

.flashcard {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.flipped,
.back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front p,
.back p {
  margin-top: 25%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stage">
  <div class="flashcard">
    <div class="front">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to iterate each row element and then call flip for each row instead of calling flip for all the elements having `flashcard` class.
thanks to @Terminator-Barbapapa for the original logic, i just made small modification.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let delay = 0;
    $('tr').each(function() {
      let row = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        row.find('.flashcard').each(function() {
          let card = $(this);

          setInterval(function() {
            card.toggleClass('flipped');
          }, 2500);
        })
      }, delay);
      delay += 1000;
    })
});
```

```css
.stage {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

.flashcard {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.flipped,
.back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front p,
.back p {
  margin-top: 15%;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="stage">
        <div class="flashcard">
          <div class="front">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="stage">
        <div class="flashcard">
          <div class="front">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="stage">
        <div class="flashcard">
          <div class="front">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="stage">
        <div class="flashcard">
          <div class="front">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="stage">
        <div class="flashcard">
          <div class="front">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="stage">
        <div class="flashcard">
          <div class="front">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="stage">
        <div class="flashcard">
          <div class="front">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="stage">
        <div class="flashcard">
          <div class="front">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="stage">
        <div class="flashcard">
          <div class="front">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <p>2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all the flipcards with the jQuery `each()` function and wrap the `setInterval()` function in a `setTimeout()` function with a delay that increases each time the `each` loop goes around.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let delay = 0;
    $('.flashcard').each(function() {
        let card = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() { 
            setInterval(function() {
                card.toggleClass('flipped');
             }, 2500);
        }, delay);
        delay += 200;
    });
});
```

```css
.stage {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000; 
}

.flashcard {
    height: 100px;  
    width: 150px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid gray; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;  
    transition: all 0.3s;               
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.flipped, .back {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); 
}

.front, .back {
    height: 100px;          
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;    
    text-align: center;   
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;       
}

.front p, .back p {
    margin-top: 25%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="stage">
                <div class="flashcard">
                    <div class="front">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="stage">
                <div class="flashcard">
                    <div class="front">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="stage">
                <div class="flashcard">
                    <div class="front">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="stage">
                <div class="flashcard">
                    <div class="front">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="stage">
                <div class="flashcard">
                    <div class="front">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="stage">
                <div class="flashcard">
                    <div class="front">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="stage">
                <div class="flashcard">
                    <div class="front">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="stage">
                <div class="flashcard">
                    <div class="front">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="stage">
                <div class="flashcard">
                    <div class="front">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how to make row flip together, not individual flip
like all top row flip first after that bottom row